# Display heading inline with following paragraph

Tags: html, css, semantic-markup

Given the following semantic markup:

```
<h3> SCOPE OF WORK. </h3>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
<p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
```

I would like to display the heading inline with the paragraph, like so:

> **SCOPE OF WORK.** Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing
>   elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt
>   ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
>
> Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi
>   ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.

**Option 1: float the heading.**

This works so long as the heading fits on one line. When it doesn't, the float forms a wide block so the paragraph starts to the right of the block, or below instead of continuing inline:

```
| SCOPE OF | Lorem |
| WORK     | ipsum |
| sit amet, consect|
```

**Option 2: display both elements inline.**

A style rule such as: `h3, h3+* {display: inline;}` might work. This assumes that they are preceded & followed by other block elements. Otherwise, other inline elements would flow into them. Also, the adjacent selector (`+`) is not available in all browsers.

**Option 3?**

Without adding unnecessary classes or wrapper elements, and keeping it valid & semantic (no `span.h3` inside the paragraph!), is there a better way to do this simple thing?

Comment: how would a display:run-in; work there? just out of curiosity

the second option is where id go, just wondering why you have to have +*

Comment: You need to put display:inline on the element that follows the heading, or else the paragraph would still display as its own block. (Just making the h3 display:inline means it would form its own anonymous block when it's surrounded by other block elements.)

Comment: @Ascherer, I'm not familiar with display:run-in; probably because it's not widely supported. But, throw me an answer if you can make a case for it: even if it's just "this is how it should work in CSS utopia".

Comment: I'm assuming that you'd be unable to predict the width of the `h3` element. (So `h3 {position: relative;}` and `h3 + p:first-line {margin-left: $width-of-h3; }` is not an option?)

Comment: On “Option 3”, ARIA lets you *restore* the semantics: `<span role="heading" aria-level="3">…</span>` should work, though really at that point I’d be as likely to add a wrapper div around the h3 and following p, and make them inline. But also you should test *both* such things in accessibility tech (AT) like popular screen readers before using it, because it’s a deviation from well-established-and-tested patterns. (Yes, even the wrapper div thing—I know that `li { display: inline }` affected some AT historically, so it’s conceivable to me that `<h3 style="display:inline">` might misbehave.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style>
h3 {display:run-in;}
p { display:block; }
div { width: 400px; }
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div>
    <h3> this is a title </h3>
    <p> this is a body of text, this is a body of text, this is a body of text, this is a body of text, this is a body of text,this is a body of text</p>
    <p> this is a body of text, this is a body of text, this is a body of text, this is a body of text, this is a body of text,this is a body of text</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

That puts the h3 tag in with the p tag.
http://www.quirksmode.org/css/display.html
doesnt work in ie7 or lower or Firefox at all, so not the best solution

Comment: ha, thanks, yeah i hadn't used it before, but its actually kinda cool. And thats a pretty handy website for checking stuff like that too, i keep it bookmarked

Comment: Quirksmode *is* pure awesome for web-dev and reference.

Comment: Seems to only work in IE (11). Doesn't work in Firefox (27), nor in Chrome (32).

Comment: Sadly, this feature is [not ready for production](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display#Browser_compatibility). It's never been supported in Firefox, and it was removed from both Safari (v8) and Chrome (v32). It does, however, describe exactly what the OP asked for.